# Referring to previous definitions/theorems/lemmas etc

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

I am relatively new to LaTeX and I am using overleaf to write a mathematical report.

I am writing a remark and refer back to a previous definition. Without explicitly typing the definition number again, is there a way to refer back to this definition?

I have attached what I want to do (although this is typed explicitly).

The aim is that should definition 1.3 change number, for example to definition 1.4, then this change would be automatically updated in this remark.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The answer whether there is a way to do this is most likely yes, but without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is very hard to provide a solution for your problem since we don't know how your document is set up. Some of us may have a working crystal ball , but others don't ... help us!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. What extra information do you think would be useful to include here?

Comment: I gave two links in my previous comment that I suggest you to follow and read. I take it that you already have some code written that you want to change in the way you describe. Post an example of this code (but make it as short as possible), then we know which approach you take and can help you with that. Which macros do you use to typeset such a defintion? Which document class and which packages do you use?

Comment: I have amended the question, I hope this helps.

Comment: In general, you often can use a `\label` to refer to something and automatically handle numbering. For example, you could set `\label{def:1}` to "Definition 1" and then later use `\ref{def:1}` to print "1" (given that this is the first label you defined in your code). But, as I stated above: without any code provided by your side, I cannot really help you.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism for cross-references is a strong point in LaTeX and you need nothing special.

The mechanism is simple: you assign a symbolic name to the object you want to refer to with the command `\label`; the reference is obtained by calling `\ref` and feeding it the symbolic name you assigned. The assignment can go out of synch if you add or delete objects, this changing the assigned numbers, but you’ll be warned about this at the end of a LaTeX run and just running LaTeX again will solve the temporary issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}

\begin{definition}\label{def:tableau}
A \emph{tableau} is a very interesting thing.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}\label{rem:tableau}
We note that the plural of \emph{tableau} is \emph{tableaux}.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
In definition~\ref{def:tableau} we were a bit terse.
See theorem~\ref{thm:main} for more information.
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:main}
This is the main theorem about tableaux.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more advanced setup can be obtained with `cleveref`. Note the slight differences in the code, but the output will be identical.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}

\begin{definition}\label{def:tableau}
A \emph{tableau} is a very interesting thing.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}\label{rem:tableau}
We note that the plural of \emph{tableau} is \emph{tableaux}.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
In \cref{def:tableau} we were a bit terse.
See \cref{thm:main} for more information.
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:main}
This is the main theorem about tableaux.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple set up. Since you did not provide any code, I don't know whether you use any specific packages, so I am usure whether this can even help you.

You can assign each defintion a label using the argument to the `definition` environment, which you can later refer to using the argument to the `remark` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{definition}
\counterwithin{definition}{section}

\newenvironment{definition}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{definition}\label{#1}%
    \noindent\textbf{Definition \thedefinition.}%
}{%
    \par%
}

\newenvironment{remark}[1]{%
    \noindent\textbf{Remark \ref{#1}.}%
}{%
    \par%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

\begin{definition}{def:a}
  This is the first definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{def:b}
  This is the second definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}{def:b}
  This is a remark to the seocnd defintion.
\end{remark}

\section{Section Two}

\begin{definition}{def:c}
  This is the third definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}{def:c}
  This is a remark to the third defintion.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}{def:a}
  This is a remark to the first defintion, referring to defintion \ref{def:b}.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply using the standard `\label` command?

Comment: @egreg I understood that the OP wanted to write a remark to a specific prior definition. So the number of the remark should match the number of the definition. This is why I chose this set up. But maybe I got the OP wrong.